# Does anybody have a link to a video or tutorial on how to georeference an image file with a crossection in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing, 3d-analyst, arcscene, references

I am looking to put together a 3D site conceptual model. I have subsurface data as well as surface data and would like to display it in ArcScene. How do I georeference a crossection so that it displays in 3D?

Comment: Why did I loose two rep for a downgrade on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few days after posting this question I finally found the procedure the ESRI rep had mentioned. Here is the link https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=133a6dc35a5f45d094b73effa68fefcb

It is not the best solution but it is available if need be.